# Issues with Powershell zip/move

Tags: powershell

I am creating a powershell script that is working for the most part; however, the zip folder I am creating cannot be opened and is appearing as a 'file' instead of a 'compressed'...

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I am not geting any errors and the file is moving, renaming, copying etc. correctly.

#### script to compress folder and move

```
Compress-Archive -Path C:\test\import -DestinationPath C:\test\archive
$filenameFormat = "archive.zip" + " " + (Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd-HHmmss")
Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
Rename-Item -Path "C:\test\archive.zip" -NewName $filenameFormat
Copy-Item -Path C:\test\$filenameFormat -Destination C:\test\allarchivefiles
Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
Move-Item -Path C:\test\$filenameFormat -Destination C:\test2
Remove-Item -Path c:\test\import\* -include *.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're choosing a filename where .zip is just in the middle and not at the end. Changing $filenameFormat to this fixes it:

```
$filenameFormat = "archive" + " " + (Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd-HHmmss") + '.zip'
```

Although I'd probably do it more compactly by setting the filename directly in a variable then using that, like this:

```
$Archive = "C:\test\archive $(Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMdd-HHmmss').zip"
Compress-Archive -Path C:\test\import -DestinationPath $Archive
Copy-Item -Path $Archive -Destination C:\test\allarchivefiles
Move-Item -Path $Archive -Destination C:\test2
Remove-Item -Path c:\test\import\* -include *.csv
```

Also removed the pauses, not sure what they were for apart from slowing the script down.